# Issue with decoding base64 PDFKit using API Gateway

Tags: node.js, base64, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, pdfkit

I have a lambda function used by API Gateway which returns a key value pair. The value in this case is a PDF document created using PDFKit represented by a base64 encoded string.

I then have a Response Template in API Gateway that decodes the base64 string using $util.base64Decode() and returns the decoded PDF doc to the client.

I sent my Content-Type and Content-disposition as follows

```
Content-Type: "'application/pdf; charset=utf-8'"
Content-disposition: "'attachment; filename=tenant.pdf'"
```

When I open the PDF I see the following which appears to still be encoded.
[image]

When I copy and paste the text into word, a google search, notes, etc I see the text I would expect.

I am not sure what is going on here, but any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: What did you set the Content-Type of the response mapping template to. Please update your question with this.

Comment: @LorenzodeLara  I updated my question based on your comment.

Comment: This should work, in theory. We've tested an equivalent use case with images that worked fine. What I can tell is that we're working on functionality to make this use case easier, and we can update this thread with more info when it's available.